# Made a mistake in creating a branch for ai50 project

Tags: git, github, repository, branch, cs50

I am doing the CS50’s Introduction to Artificial Intelligence with Python. There are some tasks that I should do and then push them on specific branches on me50/{my github username} repository.
the current task is told to be pushed like this:

using Git, push your work to https://github.com/me50/USERNAME.git, where USERNAME is your GitHub username, on a branch called ai50/projects/2023/x/knights.

I was doing that via the command line but it kept giving me errors:

*src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:me50/r-mehryab.git'*

So I tried creating a new branch via github interface in the website (in my case the branch is: ai50/projects/2023/x/knights). I made a mistake and instead of changing the source to "main", I let it be the last branch I worked with, which was: web50/projects/2020/x/wiki.

Now the branch ai50/projects/2023/x/knights seems to contain the files from the web50/projects/2020/x/wiki branch and it has become the default branch. I can not delete it or change it not to be default since I am not the repository owner. I have no idea what should I do?

p.s: Maybe I should mention that all the other branches except for ai50/projects/2023/x/knights are stale branches now, including "main" branch.

Comment: "but it kept giving me errors" What did those errors say? That's kind of a critical detail you've just left out - and one that will prevent the kind of help you probably want.

Comment: @JimRedmond Sorry you're right. this was the error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:me50/r-mehryab.git'

Comment: Btw for the error: I usually get something similar when I forgot to `git add` before commiting, so maybe this will make it work

Answer (score 0):

you should just be able to pull, delete the files, commit and push again. They could theoretically see in history that you pushed something by mistake but that's okay, no one will look at the git history of thousands of non-paying students and even if they did, it happens to everyone, you noticed and corrected your mistake.

So the solution should be:

```
    git stash push
    git checkout ai50/projects/2023/x/knights 
    git pull
    git rm <your web50 files>
    git add <all the and only the files you want to push>
    git commit 
    git push
```